# Is there a way for creating a spring context which can run before all of my junit unit tests which are on different classes?

Tags: java, spring, junit, jndi

Sorry I did not research this issue deeply on the internet or on SO. So down voting is welcome. After all I have a feeling this may be a dump question. However I am giving a shot.

I have a project which will contain all of the unit tests. All of the unit tests require a setup which basically creates a jndi namespace. I am doing this with @Before tag on each of my unit test class. So I am doing lots of copy paste which is irritating me a little. Is there a way of creating a singleton class which creates this jndi namespace for all of my unit tests possibly with spring or any other way.

Comment: Create a class, put the code in an init method (annotated with `@PostConstruct` or using the `InitializingBean` interface). Let y our test configuration load that class... Be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the M. Deinum sollution. If he posted the answer I would accept it.

I created a master class like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JndiInit{

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException, SQLException, NamingException{
        System.out.println("Mastersetup for initializing jndi namespace");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("Tear down");
    }

}
```

My unit tests uses a spring context
Test 1 :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/testContext.xml")
public class Test1{


    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test 1");
    }

}
```

And Test2

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/testContext.xml")
public class Test2 {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test 2");
    }
}
```

And my spring context is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="tr.com.mhrs.test.base.jndifactory.JndiInit">

    </bean>
</beans>
```

It successfully achieved what I want.

```
Mastersetup for initializing jndi namespace
test 1
test 2
Tear down
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: just a comment here.  If you start creating more test classes, you would have to provide them with @ContextConfiguration("/testContext.xml") for each one of them. For that, you can pull it out on a centralized parent class, so that you dont have to modify all classes tomorrow if you do change your context file name(which in my opinion would not happen, but still just mentioning it :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the JNDI logic in a JNDITestExecutionListener class which implements

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener
```

and annotate your tests with the listener as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(JNDITestExecutionListener.class)
```

Another option is to create a JUnit rule for this.

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class which has a method which would do your JNDI setup.

EDIT: On second thoughts, this need not be an abstract. It can be, if you want to enforce some setup semantics on all your test classes, but it doesnt have to be.

Annotate this method with a @BeforeClass.

Now, extend all your Unit test classes with this parent class. Something like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:conf/spring/test-context.xml")
public abstract class AbstractParent{

@BeforeClass
setupJNDI(){
....
}

}

public class MyTestClass
      extends AbstractParent{

@Test
public void myTestMethod(){
....
}

}
```

About @[BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) -

Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization. Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the current class.